# representation of enum member values in swift?

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum CompassPoint {
case north, east, south, west
}

var compassHeading = CompassPoint.west
```

I've read that "The case values of an enumeration are actual values, not just another way of writing their raw values." I'm confused about this statement. If cases are new types themselves, then shouldn't it be initialized as:

```
var compassHeading = CompassPoint.west()
```

According to apple, enums don't include implicit initializers.. which confuses me even more.

Comment: I found the first statement on [a blog](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/enumerations/) and the second statement from Apple's official [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html). Guess which one is more creditable? Not everything you read on the internet is true

Comment: then does this mean enumeration cases are initialized before calling them? Are they instances of the enum type?

Comment: @CodeDifferent If _typing out_ a `case` of an `enum` where the `case` has associated values, then the _type_ of this `case` will be a higher order function with arguments matching the associated values and return type matching the `enum` itself. Since different cases are allowed to have different types (and number) of associated values, naturally the _type_ of a typed out `enum` can differ. The importance here is to differ between an `enum` _instance_ (which always have a given case as _value_) and explicit _types_ of the cases themselves (when not values!).

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR;

If *typing out* a `case` of an `enum` where the `case` has associated values, then the *type* of this `case` will be a higher order function with arguments matching the associated values and return type matching the `enum` itself. Since different cases are allowed to have different types (and number) of associated values, naturally the *type* of a typed out `enum` `case` can differ. The importance here is to differ between an `enum` *instance* (which always have a given `case` as *value*) and the explicit *types* of the cases themselves (when not values).

---

#### An `enum` *instance* is always associated with a `case`, and always have the *type* of the `enum`

I don't know the source of your quotations, but [the Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) is quite straightforward on describing each `case` as value:

> An enumeration defines a common type for a group of *related values* and
>   enables you to work with those values in a type-safe way within your
>   code.

#### The *typed* cases of `enum`:s with cases of different associated values will define different types of higher order function types, all returning the type of the `enum`

But in addition the value-view of the `case` *instance* of an `enum`, it might be noted that each `case` (typed out!) itself has a *type* (although not a "new" type in the sense that `struct Foo {}` would), which may differ between different cases of the same `enum`. If the cases have no associated value(s), this type simply equals the `enum` itself, but if the `case` use associated values, then the *type* of the `case` will be a higher order function type with arguments typed as the associated values and return type being the `enum` type itself. Since different cases can have different associated values, it naturally follows that different cases can correspond to different types.

> Alternatively, enumeration cases can specify associated values of any
>   type to be stored along with each different case value, much as unions
>   or variants do in other languages. You can define a common set of
>   related cases as part of one enumeration, each of which has a
>   different set of values of appropriate types associated with it.
>
> ...
>
> You can define Swift enumerations to store associated values of
>   any given type, *and the value types can be different for each case of
>   the enumeration* if needed.

```
enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz(Int) // Int associated value
    case bax()    // Void associated value
}

print(type(of: Foo.bar)) // Foo
print(type(of: Foo.baz)) // (Int) -> Foo
print(type(of: Foo.bax)) // () -> Foo

func foo(_ closure: (Int) -> Foo) -> Foo {
    return closure(42)
}

let foobaz = foo(Foo.baz) // 'foobar' is 'Foo.baz' (ass. value 42)

let foobar = foo(Foo.bar) // wont compile, type mismatch
let foobax = foo(Foo.bax) // wont compile, type mismatch
```

Now, since different cases have different types (when typed out, not when part of a `Foo` instance), "initialization" of given `case` to a given `enum` instance will look different depending on whether the `case` have any associated values or not.

```
enum Foo {
    case bar
    case baz(Int) // Int associated value
    case bax()    // Void associated value
}

var foo = Foo.bar // no associated values
foo = Foo.baz(42) // expects Int associated value: needs to be _invoked_(/called)
foo = Foo.bax()   // expects empty tuple '()' associated value: needs to be _invoked_(/called)
```

As you can see, a `case` *instance* without an associated value is instantiated simply by typing out the `enum` type and the case (since the type of this case will be the `enum` itself: compare with `Foo.bar`), whereas cases with associated values (even `()`) will need to be invoked when instantiated. This invokation, particularly for the `bax()` case above, might look a lot like some implicit initialization, but its simply the invokation of a closure type to receive an *instance* of the return type `Foo`.

```
let aVoidFooClosure = Foo.bax
let aFooInstance = aVoidFooClosure()
  // invoke! This now have value 'Foo.bax' (empty tuple '()' associated value)
```

Comment: so is it safe to assume that case instances do not have to be initialized like a struct or class with () because they are instances themselves?

Comment: @User9123 see the additional example in my edit: a `case` _instance_ without an associated value is instantiated simply by typing out the `enum` type and the case (since the type of this case will be the `enum` itself: compare with `Foo.bar`), whereas cases with associated values (even `()`) will need to be "invoked" when instantiated. This invokation, particularly for the `bax()` case above, might look a lot like some implicit initialization, but its simply the invokation of a closure type to receive an _instance_ of the return type `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

> If cases are new types themselves, then shouldn't it be initialized as:
>
> ```
> var compassHeading = CompassPoint.west()
> ```

It's just a matter of notation. But I think you can justify it to yourself like this.

It is possible to add an initializer of the kind you seem to expect, but then what you are initializing is CompassWest, not a particular case:

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case west
    init() {
        self = .west
    }
}

let cp = CompassPoint()
```

Moreover, if CompassPoint's `west` case had an associated value, what you ask for is just the sort of thing you *would* say:

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case west(Int)
}
let cp = CompassPoint.west(25)
```

But since no case has an associated value, all `CompassPoint.west` objects are effectively the same object. No state is maintained — remember, an enum has no stored properties. So this is not like instantiating a struct or a class. `CompassPoint.west` is not *an* instantiation of this case of CompassPoint; it *the* one and only `CompassPoint.west` in the universe.

(In that sense, the case `.west` is more like a static property of a struct than like an instance of a class. And so the notation for referring to it is just like the notation for referring to a static property of a struct.)

Comment: thx! I've been wondering about this too. Swift might be implicitly defining  enum types or cases as static but I couldn't find much info about this so I'm not presuming anything.